# What desktop environments can group window icons in the taskbar like Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, window-manager, desktop-environments, taskbar

I find it much faster to identify a window in the taskbar (window list) by its icon,

[image: taskbar with icon only]

rather than by its text:

[image: taskbar with icon and text]

The problem with most graphical interfaces I've [switched among](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162516/switching-window-manager-desktop-environments) is that they don't group windows, and if you have more terminals or file managers, they'll just clutter the taskbar and you won't know which is which. Windows 7 offers a relatively elegant solution to this by grouping similar window icons together.

**Question**: What Linux [desktop environments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/whatisthedifferencebetweenadesktopenvironment-andawindowmanager#comment289154_20435) have this functionality? If addons exist that provide it, that's alright.

For reference, a Cinnamon applet that sort of does this is [Window List With App Grouping](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/16).

Comment: If one of the answers solves your original problem, please Accept the answer.

Comment: @landroni: what if more than one answer solves the problem?

Comment: Well, [you cannot accept two answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5282/can-i-accept-two-answers-on-a-question), it seems. So you could: (1) `accept` the answer that is most pertinent and `upvote` a 2nd answer, and (2) make a bold-formatted 'UPDATE' to your OP to indicate what solutions solved your problem.

Comment: Alternatively, group all relevant answers that optimally fix your original issue into your own answer, and accept that. (But in that case you don't offer reputation points to those who answered your question.)

Answer (score 5):

**Unity's launcher** groups windows belonging to one application in the same icon.

[image: Four icons from Unity's launcher]

For example, in this screenshot, I have two Firefox windows open, and one Thunderbird window open. The Firefox icon in the launcher has two corresponding arrows on the left to indicate this, and the Thunderbird icon has one arrow. If I click the Firefox icon, I can choose between its two windows, which are immediately rearranged and laid out on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

- LXDE's LX Panel has this capability. Right-click the taskbar and select "Task Bar (Window List)" Settings. Check "Combine multiple application windows into a single button". If "icons only" is also selected, there's no visual indication that an icon may represent more than one window.
- There's also [XFCE4-panel](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start) in which a task list item could be added [[1](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,98098.msg840526.html#msg840526)].

Comment: Why the downvote here?

Answer (score 2):

[Dockbarx](https://launchpad.net/dockbar) does exactly what you want. It can be combined with AWN and others easily.

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/7-beautiful-dockbarx-themes-taskbar.html?m=1

If you want to see this in action, download the free version of [Zorin OS](http://zorinos.com/), which has done this.

Answer (score 2):

In [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org), you can easily configure the `Window Buttons` plug-in on the panel to emulate a `Windows 7`-like look & feel. See screenshot: 
[image]

To do so, `right-click` on the plug-in's handle, access `Properties`, then uncheck the `Show button labels` option. You may also consider modifying the `Sorting order` option to something that you prefer (personally I always go for `None, allow DnD`).

Another possibility in `Xfce` is the less well-known [xfce4-tasklist-plugin](http://git.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-taskbar-plugin/), which specifically "mimicks the Windows 7 taskbar (pinning applications, etc)".

See this related discussion on `xfce-dev` ML: [tweaking Window Buttons defaults](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.desktop.xfce.devel.version4/21197).

Comment: In the recent version (xfce 4.12) grouping is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

I personally just stick with Gnome Shell for this feature though with the Dash extension.  You can install gnome shell extensions at https://extensions.gnome.org/

If you have say multiple Google Chrome windows open you just right click on the icon and select which window you want.

Not exactly the same as windows 7, but you use a right click instead of a left to view the window.  If you left click it takes you to the window you viewed last.  I prefer this functionality.

You can also look at docky, cario dock, awn.  I prefer docky.  AWN has a lot of features though for just a seperate more customizable "dock", "dash", "launcher", or thing.

I also use alt+tab alot.  In gnome shell you also have access to the super key.  It makes viewing all your applications pretty easy.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

KDE Plasma Desktop can have the taskbar like Windows 7.

In KDE Plasma 5, there are three steps to follow:

1. **Right-click** on the bottom panel, somewhere next to the K-menu icon
2. Click **Alternatives...** to see list of Alternative Widgets
3. Select **Icon-only Task Manager** and then click **Switch**

That is all, launch few similar applications to see the result. With Icon-only Task Manager, application icons will always be combined and grouped together.

[image: KDE Plasma 5 with icon-only task manager]

**Discrepancy**: By default, a click on the application icons will activate a certain desktop effect. To disable this behaviour, Go to **Settings > Desktop Behavior > Desktop Effects** and then, locate and **clear the checkbox** for "Present Windows". The desktop effect will be replaced by a small pop-up window as shown in the screenshot above.

Following above steps, the taskbar option "Always combine, hide labels" in Windows 7 can be reproduced similarly in KDE Plasma Desktop. This has been possible beginning from KDE Plasma 4, but the newer generation KDE Plasma 5 has simplified the setup.