# Gnome issue with different modes

Tags: gnome

Hello Guys i am new to Linux and currently i installed the ubuntu 2014 with gnome shell 3.10.4 .At the log on screen there were different modes of gnome they were Gnome,Gnome Home ,Gnome flashback (meta city) ,Gnome flashback (Com pi z). So what are they and to which i should switch to for betterment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `different modes` are the different GNOME desktop Environment versions, choose the one that works for you!

- Gnome

  - is the default GNOME Desktop Environment
- Gnome Home

  - (Not sure what this is)
- Gnome flashback (metacity)

  - Uses the metacity window manager
- Gnome flashback (Compiz)

  - Uses the Compiz compositing window manager

---

**Further Reading**:

- [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65083/36315)
- [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/36315)
- [What is the difference between a desktop environment and a window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18078/36315)
- [Desktop environment - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)