# VB Compiz Transitions are slow

Tags: graphics, virtualbox, compiz

I'm using i3 and Compiz with Ubuntu. Though Compiz animations just as simple as fading in and out seems so sluggish.

My computer has a GTX 970 and a i7-4770k with 8GB RAM Corsair Vengeance. Is there any way to make it not as laggy / sluggish / slow? I'm running Ubuntu in a VB for a work environment so when I'm done working, I can easily switch back to Windows (granted my boot time is only 4 secs with a ssd, but it's still time I have to wait).

My Ubuntu VB settings are:

- 4096MB RAM
- 4 CPU Cores being used @ 100% exe cap.
- Max VRAM (128 MB) with 3D acceleration on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity (Ubuntu's default desktop environment) is a relatively demanding DE, and requires a good graphics card and drivers to run well.

Unfortunately, the 3D video drivers for Linux when inside a VM are terrible. Even VMware who makes a commercial virtualization solution doesn't provide 3D drivers.

The best fix here is to install a different desktop environment. For example, XFCE would be a good choice.

In order to do that, just open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

Also, you did install the Guest Additions kernel modules in the VM, right?

## Edit

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager) explains the difference between a window manger and a DE.

Comment: Guest Additions, like mounting the Guest Additions iso and installing them? If so, then yes.

Comment: @ErraticFox - Correct.

Comment: I'd say 'relatively demanding ' would be more accurate and concise then the awkward "EXTREMELY demanding (relatively speaking)".

Comment: @mikewhatever - Edited.

Comment: I'm still new to Linux, so can you answer what's the difference between a WM and DE? Because don't they both technically "Manage Windows"? I always get, not confused, but *in a way* confused as you're able to use both at the same time.

Comment: @ErraticFox - See here for an explanation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager

Comment: @ErraticFox - Also, if you want a lightweight DE and a lightweight WM, you should install the LXDE DE since it uses the OpenBox WM.

Comment: Wait, I was using i3. So was Unity also running in the background? Because I was really enjoying i3.

Comment: @ErraticFox - As far as I can tell i3 is a WM and not a DE.