# How to make Ubuntu fast like Lubuntu? (older PC)

Tags: unity, lubuntu, lxde

If I use LXDE can Ubuntu be fast like Lubuntu? Or are there differences other than the desktop environment? If there are what changes can I make?

I ended up switching to Ubuntu because Lubuntu had some sound issues for me with programs I wanted to use and I already had an Ubuntu install disk handy. Maybe I was missing some drivers or something but I'd rather avoid formatting and/or installing another OS at this point

Comment: If you have Lubuntu 16.04.x LTS, you can install `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol`. It should give you good quality of the sound. If there are problems with codecs and similar, you can install `lubuntu-restricted-extras`. - You can try installing LXDE (program package `lxde`) into your Ubuntu, log out and at the log in screen select the LXDE 'session' by clicking of the Ubuntu icon. But be warned, there can be problems with Unity and another desktop environment, and it is difficult (maybe impossible) to remove LXDE without causing damage to the remaining system.

Comment: Did you already install LXDE? In such case, how exactly?

Comment: I used the sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop command.

Comment: The difference between L/Ubuntu IS THE DE - DE here is defined as the window manager + default set of applications. If the system is slower with the default Unity it is most likely due to the 3d effects of Unity. As an alternate to Unity / Lubuntu you could use KDE or XFCE. See also any number of websites that compare DE

Comment: "I ended up switching..... Because had some sound issues" if this is an XY problem, better focus on the real issue: audio.

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` installs not only LXDE but also all the Lubuntu specific tweaks and program packages. Please tell us how it works! Installing lubuntu-desktop into standard Ubuntu is mixing the desktop environments. Dual booting is different:The two operating systems are separate and independent of each other and the performance of each of them is not affected by the other system (except that part of the disk space is occupied by the other operating system).

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Ubuntu and Lubuntu is that Lubuntu is lighter, less resource hungry and more energy-efficient as it uses lightweight applications, including the LXDE desktop (Lightweight X11 desktop environment). Lubuntu is ideal for users having low hardware specs. Both Ubuntu and Lubuntu share the same core system and repositories. Ubuntu is the original creation with Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu all basically the same systems with different desktop environments and default applications.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

Comment: If I dual boot with Lubuntu will it affect performance after signing in?

Comment: The difference between L/Ubuntu IS THE DE - DE here is defined as the window manager + default set of applications. What you describe as "less resource hungry and more energy-efficient as it uses lightweight applications, including the LXDE desktop " is the definition of a DE - http://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager