# Desktop environment that enables split screen shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, window-manager

At the moment I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to align windows on my screens with `compiz`.

I don't really like using `compiz` as I don't like the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> feel to switch windows, among other niggles.

Are there any environments that have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> or similar to split windows as a default?

Comment: Does my script [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/613990/85695) help?

Comment: In Unity, you can use `Ctrl+Alt+Numpad` to place windows.

Answer (score 1):

Today I switched to Gnome desktop. You can use the exact same shortcut to split the screen.

[image: Split Screen with Gnome]

Answer (score 1):

Of course most window managers (see [What is the difference between a desktop environment and a window manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18078/what-is-the-difference-between-a-desktop-environment-and-a-window-manager)) offer shortkeys to change window position and size, but with `wmctrl` you can control such things simply yourself, e.g.

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,200,200,640,480
```

to change the active window's size to 640x480px and position it at 200, 200. See [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) for the whole story.

Once you figured out the commands you want just assign them to the desired shortcut using your desktop environment's GUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit almost all Compiz keyboard shortcuts to your liking in [Compiz Config Settings Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is Cinnamon Desktop.  I switched from Unity about 2 months ago and couldn't be happier.  Super+direction moves windows in many different ways.  You can do left/right half, top/bottom, full-screen and even corners with just super and directions. By the way,  it's default functionality.  Check it out.